# Como crear una matriz en SQL? SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportviewer, ssrs

La verdad es que no tengo mucha idea de como realizar lo siguiente en SQL, por eso quiero pedirles su ayuda para saber como realizarlo, los pongo en contexto... tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: Tabla]

Y me gustaria realizar una matriz que quede de la siguiente manera:

[image: Estructura]
[image: Resultado de la matriz]

El detalle aqui es que esto primero lo realice automaticamente en SSRS pero tuve el problema que cuando ingreso un usuario que no tiene un curso no me lo muestra en los resultados, pero si ingreso un usuario que tenga aunque sea un solo curso este si me lo muestra con su calif indicada y con los demas cursos en blanco(Ej.clave:10068) y lo que quisiera resolver realizandolo desde SQL es que tambien me muestre el usuario ingresado que no tiene ningun curso, por ejemplo si ingreso el usuario 1234 y este no se encuentre en mi tabla, en mi matriz solo me devuelva la clave del empleado y en sus cursos los deje en blanco, esto para saber que ese usuario no cuenta con ningun curso, ya que esto mismo en SSRS no me lo muestra.

Espero que me puedan ayudar, estuve buscando pero no puedo encontrar la solucion. Gracias!

Comment: Te comparto un link sobre como transponer filas a columnas que es un problema asociado a lo que tu necesitas.  https://www.sqlshack.com/es/multiples-opciones-para-transponer-filas-en-columnas/

Comment: ¿Cómo obtienes la primer tabla que muestras? Es probable que un pequeño cambio ahí permita que se genere correctamente en SSRS sin mayores cambios.